# Relational Tables - Select Only Rows in Table A That Don't Exist as ID in Table B

Tags: mysql, select, key

I have table A that stores courses and table B that stores current progress of users.

table A has unique ID column for each course (courseID) which also exists in table B with the same name (thus their relation).

I want to get all rows from table A whose IDs don't exist in table B. (e.g. no user has currently entered this course)

The two tables don't use foreign keys, just a column with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

TRY

```
SELECT A.* FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B ON USING (courseID)
WHERE B.courseID IS NULL
```

Comment: also you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.courseID NOT IN (SELECT courseID FROM B);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `tableA`
  LEFT JOIN `tableB` ON `tableA`.`ID`=`tableB`.`ID`
  WHERE `tableB`.`ID` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?
If you're using Oracle, I think you want:

```
select A.student_code from A where not exists
( select 'x' from B where B.student_code = A.student_code)
```

At least that's what I think you were asking for..